# Python arcade library function read_tmx not working

Tags: python, arcade

Following [this code](https://github.com/realpython/materials/blob/master/arcade-platformer/arcade_platformer/04_define_player.py) from [this tutorial](https://realpython.com/platformer-python-arcade/) I'm getting this error

```
DeprecationWarning: The read_tmx function has been replaced by the new TileMap class.
```

The code I'm using is

```
game_map = arcade.tilemap.read_tmx(str(map_path))
```

I'm not sure if this code is outdated now or what but I can't seem to find a way to get my tilemap to load properly.

Answer (score 2):

[This tutorial](https://realpython.com/platformer-python-arcade/) was built on outdated `Arcade` version:

`This tutorial uses Python 3.9 and arcade 2.5.5 throughout.`

Currently latest `Arcade` version is `2.6.1`. So I see several options here:

- downgrade your `Arcade` version to `2.5.5` (not recommended though)
- update tutorial code to the latest `Arcade` version
- use [official](https://api.arcade.academy/en/latest/examples/index.html) `Arcade` examples (best choice imo)